# Lapack SPPTRF available?

Tags: matlab, lapack, factorization

do you know if MATLAB supports the LAPACK `spptrf` function.

This function is quite a bargain when you gotta compute Cholesky factorization of a huge positive definite symmetric matrix.

It allows for the factorization by only giving the upper triangular matrix, stored as uni-dimensional matrix, as input.

Or, else, is `chol` built-in function already using `spptrf` internally?

**EDIT**

I have been able to find the `lapack` library on the File Exchange http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16777-lapack, with the desired implementation of the `spptrf` function.

**EDIT 2**

MATLAB running on my machine is fatally crashing each time I call `spptrf`.

Is there any alternative way to directly handle this function?